# Как настроить доступ из интернета к нескольким сайтам на OpenServer?

Tags: сервер, openserver

Есть следующие сайты на OpenServer

```
dev.test1.ru
dev.test2.ru
dev.test3.ru
```

Внешний IP, предположим: `82.111.222.333`

Как и что сделать, чтобы на эти все сайты можно было зайти из интернета?

Хотелось бы, чтоб можно было обратиться вот так:

```
82.111.222.333/dev.test1.ru - открывался бы один сайт
82.111.222.333/dev.test2.ru - открывался бы другой сайт
82.111.222.333/dev.test3.ru - открывался бы третий сайт
```

На данный момент могу привязать через alias только один сайт... Т.е. вбив `82.111.222.333` откроется один из сайтов `test`, в зависимости, что привяжу.

А хочется всё и сразу :-)

Comment: в твоем случае твой IP и так должен вести на сервер, а сервер иметь папки dev.testN.ru. Ну а при обращении на `82.111.222.333/dev.test1.ru` он тебе и откроет index файл в папке. Я так реализовывал для денвера загрузки локального сервера из вне

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Пробовал так (вообще как только не пробовал))), но, увы, так он не открывает. Пишет 404 и всё

Comment: не может быть, для IP адреса `dev.testN.ru` это папка, как он может её не открывать. Значит проблема в чем то другом.

Comment: Ну вот так вот. Да это логично, но нифига. Какая-то логика там заложена..... Зато если сделать в папке `domains` папку, допустим `routing`... в ней расположить все те папки.... далее в `alias` прописать `82.111.222.333 => routing` то тогда будет работать..... но это как-то костыльно... делать роутинг для сервера, который итак вроде как должен уже роутить папку `domains`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я поанализировал некоторые факты:

При обращении по адресу `myIP/domain` не открывается нужный сайт, хотя по логике должен, ведь для IP адреса `dev.testN.ru` это папка, которую он должен открывать.

Если есть папка `localhost` и в ней различные сайты, то в адресной строке можно обращаться `localhost/someSiteName` - все открывается. А папка `localhost` соответствует адресу `127.0.0.1` (локальной машине)

В документации `openServer` написано:

> Чтобы при наборе IP адреса вашего компьютера открывался определенный
>   локальный сайт, можно создать алиас вида ваш_внешний_ip =>
>   ваш_локальный_домен

---

Итак. Как сделать несколько  сайтов на внешку:

1) В папке `domains` удаляем папку `localhost` (или изменяем её название, чтоб убрать ассоциацию с 127.0.0.1)

2) В папке `domains` создаем папку, которая послужит корнем для доменов. Например `routeFolder`. В ней уже будут лежать папки `dev.test1.ru, dev.test2.ru, 
dev.test3.ru  и т.д.`

3) В настройках -> вкладка "Сервер" -> IP-адрес сервера ставим наш внешний IP

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) В настройках -> вкладка "Алиасы" -> привязываем IP к папке `routeFolder` и сохраняем настройку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё, перезагружаем сервер.

P.S. Не забываем открыть порт для входа с внешки.

P.P.S. При наборе IP будет видна папка с нашими доменами. Чтоб их не было видно, можно в корень (т.е. в папку `routeFolder`) кинуть `.htaccess`, который будет автоматом с корня перенаправлять, например, на *сайт№1*

Comment: что прописать в .htaccess для перенаправления