# Как через open Server сделать доступными несколько сайтов в локальной сети?

Tags: openserver

Как сделать доступными несколько сайтов в локальной сети через open server? Один я уже сделал, второй прописать не могу так как у меня 1 ip.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а причем тут один IP? добавляешь еще сайты тут же, с тем же ip. Обращаться будут к нему через alias, то есть через имя домена, который написан с правой стороны.... ты же когда 100500 сайтов располагаешь в папке domains - ты же любой можешь открыть в любое время, хотя айпишник у тебя всегда один — 127.0.0.1 ....... также и тут.......главное папку `localhost`, скорее всего, придется удалить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508414/191482

Comment: А зачем вы локальный IP замазали? Он же не несёт никакой конфиденциальной информации?

Comment: Когда пытаюсь добавить еще 1 алиас пишет что под таким адруссом уже есть 1 алиас:

http://prntscr.com/f5rf9q

Comment: попробуй сделать так, как написано в ссылке в моем первом комменте. сделать единую точку входа

Answer (score 1):

в папке domains создаете новую папку с названием проекта. внутрь кидаете весь код проекта. Перезапускаете опер сервер. Вбиваете в браузере название проекта и он открывается